# List is not updated for existing clients in socketIO

Tags: node.js, angular, sockets, socket.io

I am working on chat application, using socketIO

Whenever user signed in sucessfully, user is navigated to dashboard and list of current loggedin users will be displayed.
Whenever new user is signed in, existing user list is not getting updated.

Adding the necessary code here

events: backend

```
let verifyClaim = require("./tokenLib");
let socketio = require("socket.io");
let tokenLibs = require('./tokenLib');

let setService = (server) => {
  let onlineUsers = [];
  let io = socketio.listen(server);

  let myio = io.of('')
  myio.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log(' emitting verify user');
    socket.emit("verifyUser", "");
    socket.on('set-user', (authToken) => {
      console.log(authToken);
      tokenLibs.verifyTokenWithoutSecret(authToken, (user, err,) => {
        if (user) {
          console.log(user);
          let currentUser = user;
          socket.userId = currentUser._id;
          let fullName = `${currentUser.name}`
          console.log(`${fullName} is online`);
          socket.emit(currentUser._id, `${fullName} is online`)
          let userObj = { userId: currentUser._id, name: fullName }
          onlineUsers.push(userObj);
          console.log(onlineUsers)
          socket.emit('userlist', onlineUsers)
        }
        else {
          socket.emit('auth-error', { status: 500, error: 'Please provide valid token ' })
        }
      })
    })
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
      console.log('user is disconnected');
      let removeUserId = onlineUsers.map(function (user) { return user.userId }).indexOf(socket.userId)
      onlineUsers.splice(removeUserId, 1)
      console.log(onlineUsers)
    })
  })
}

module.exports = { setService: setService }
```

socket service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SocketService {
  public prod = 'https://todolistbe.herokuapp.com/api/v1';
  public dev = 'http://localhost:3001';
  public baseUrl = this.dev;
  private socket;
  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    this.socket=io('http://localhost:3001')
   }
   public verifyUser=()=>{
     return Observable.create((observer)=>{
       this.socket.on('verifyUser',(data)=>{
         observer.next(data);
       })
     })
   }
   public setUser=(authToken)=>{
     this.socket.emit("set-user",authToken)
   }
   public userList=()=>{
    return Observable.create((observer)=>{
      this.socket.on('userlist',(data)=>{
        observer.next(data);
      })
    })
  }
  public welcomeUser=(userid)=>{
    return Observable.create((observer)=>{
      this.socket.on(userid,(data)=>{
        observer.next(data);
      })
    })
  }
  public disconnectUser = () => {
    return Observable.create((observer) => {
      this.socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        observer.next()
      })
    })
  }    
}
```

dashboard:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ThemePalette } from '@angular/material/core';
import { SocketService } from '../../socket.service';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
export interface Task {
  name: string;
  completed: boolean;
  color: ThemePalette;
  subtasks?: Task[];
}


@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css'],
  providers: [SocketService]
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  public authToken: any = localStorage.getItem('authToken');
  public userList: any = [];
  public userNotification;
  allComplete: boolean = false;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.verifyUserConfirmation();
    this.getOnlineUsers();
  }

  public verifyUserConfirmation: any = () => {
    this.SocketService.verifyUser().subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(this.authToken)
      this.SocketService.setUser(this.authToken);
      this.getOnlineUsers();
    })
  }

  selected = 'option2';
  toggleNavbar() {
    console.log('toggled' + this.isMenuOpened);
    this.isMenuOpened = !this.isMenuOpened;
  }

  getOnlineUsers() {
    // this.SocketService.welcomeUser(localStorage.getItem('id')).subscribe((data)=>{
    //   this.userNotification=data;
    //   console.log("hi:"+this.userNotification)
    // })
    this.SocketService.userList().subscribe((user) => {

      this.userList = [];
      for (let x in user) {
        let tmp = { 'user': x, 'name': user[x] }
        this.userList.push(tmp);
      }
      console.log(this.userList)

    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Who emit this event, socket.on('set-user',(authToken)=>{ ... });
Are you sure code inside the block is executed?

Comment: Yes ! I could able to see online user list from my client , but when I login from another browser , j am getting two users in the list. Ideally list should be updated with first client as well .

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to emit an event with all other users, we should use myio.emit instead of socket.io.
Issue is resolved when i made necessary changed in my backend events library